# Drupal 8 hook_views_pre_build no effect

Tags: php, drupal, hook, drupal-8

I'm trying to override some view by using the hook_views_pre_build hook. Following the documentation:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/8.1.x

My module is named "mymodule", I've got:

```
<?php
//... some code that works
// and my hook:
function mymodule_views_pre_build(&$view) {
   var_dump("hello"); die();
}
```

And that has no effect at all. Trying other hooks works, for example "mymodule_preprocess_page" is ok.

I do a "drush cr" each time, I tried other hook as "mymodule_views_pre_exec" that has no effect. It seems that Drupal 8.1 doesn't execute hook_views_XXX

Anyone can help me to resolve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the doc says:

hook_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view)

Try with ViewExecutable $view instead of &$view ?

Comment: +1 to this: `call_user_func_array($function, $args)` seems to fail silently in D8 if the function's declared argument types aren't right. But you should also either `use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;` at the top of the file, or specify the full namespaced class in the function declaration, as otherwise the class will resolve to `\ViewExecutable` and be incorrect.